# Desktop Ubuntu 13.04 Nexus 7 (grouper) mirror download?

Tags: nexus-7, ubuntu-for-android

The guide for installing Ubuntu on Nexus 7 takes me to http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-preinstalled/current/ which 404's.
 I have searched with no luck for mirror images of Ubuntu Desktop (not phablet).

Are there are any official mirrors left or anyone got a mirror download link?
If it is of any significance I am going to use it with Multirom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/raring/release/ubuntu-13.04-preinstalled-desktop-armhf+nexus7.img.gz) is the last Ubuntu 13.04 Preinstalled Desktop image for Nexus 7.

Comment: I think **Ubuntu-Touch** *core (desktop), raring-160* (12-Jun) is an orphan. Any new daily/release will be a different code and/or *saucy* (13.10) based. *I have this on a (spare) **Nexus-7**, and it still needs a lot of work ..*